# MobileFirst on iOS: start Google Maps and let user return

Tags: ios, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I use a standard Maps protocol for iOS in my MobileFirst 7.0 hybrid app:

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=...">...</a>
```

The Google Maps app opens correctly, however there is no possibility to return back to my app. The iOS apps list shows my app icon with Google Maps screen. The Google Maps UI has no exit button to return back. I would expect there to be two separate processes: my app and Google Maps.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this intended? If so, how should one go about something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Apple guide, this will open either Safari or the Maps app. It does not mention anything on returning back to the app, so that's just that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Edit: but to get it to work in web apps, like in the case of IBM MobileFirst, where the app is rendered in a WebView inside an app, you *should not* follow Apple's guidelines to use a URL such as: `http://maps.apple.com?q=...` but rather only `maps:q=...`.

By using the second option the actual Apple Maps app will launch instead of replacing your app with Google Maps.

Comment: Do you mean that until iOS 9 the user, after having started an external app, has to: press home (minimize app); double-press home (show apps list); swipe the app away (stop app); start the app again?

Comment: That has been the experience since, well, forever in iOS.

Comment: Well, no, you don't have to quit the app... you just want to select the app to go back to it... You wrote that you click a link and it opens another app... so you have 2 apps running, so you just want to switch between them

Comment: that's actually the problem: it opens GMaps inside my app process. I.e. I only get one icon in the process list - my app icon, but showing GMaps UI. There is no way to switch between the two, as there is just one. iOS 8.1.3.

Comment: @AndreyChirikba, See my updated answer for a solution.

Comment: Great, this has worked. Thanks, Idan! Only thing: there should be no http:// scheme before the actual maps: scheme, i.e.: maps:q=... Please update and I will accept your answer.

Comment: for me it didn't. `http://maps:q=...` opened the URL in the same view as my app (same as in my original question). The URL was unreachable, so it gave a blank page.